# Problem with \left\langle \right\rangle in continued fractions

Tags: equations, delimiters

```
$$
 {\bf A}_3+
   \left\langle{\cfrac{\bf I}{{\bf A}_2+
     \left\langle\cfrac{\bf I}{{\bf A}_1+
      \left\langle\cfrac{\bf I}{{\bf A}_0}\right\rangle_1^{-1}}
     \right\rangle_2^{-1}}}
   \right\rangle_3^{-1}
$$
```

Indices 1, 2, 3 should be close to the corresponding brackets (I do not know how to do that) see a picture

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately, `\langle` and `\rangle` have a maximum size.

Comment: How to move indices 1,2,3 to the lower angle of brackets?

Comment: That wouldn't help, I guess.

Comment: You haven't said what format you are using (which might affect possible answers) using `$$` and `\bf` I thought it was plain TeX rather than latex, but I note you use `\cfrac` which is usually defined by the amsmath latex package?

Comment: This is the standard LaTeX which allows to use $$ and \bf = \mathbf. Yes, this is with amsmath.

Comment: @shsmn not so; `$$\ne\[ \]\ne$$`, and `\bf` doesn't even have the same syntax as `\mathbf` (for `$$` see [uk tex faq](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=dolldoll) )

Comment: @shhmn `\bf` has been deprecated since latex2e was introduced in 1993, and `$$` has never been supported in latex

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `scalerel` package (I *knew* it can be useful):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\bA}{\mathbf{A}}
\newcommand{\bI}{\mathbf{I}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \bA_3+ 
  {\stretchleftright
    {\bigg\langle}
    {\dfrac{\bI}{\bA_2+
     {\stretchleftright
      {\bigg\langle}
      {\dfrac{\bI}{\bA_1+
       {\stretchleftright
         {\bigg\langle}
         {\dfrac{\bI}{\bA_0}}
         {\bigg\rangle}}_{\!1}^{\!-1}}}
      {\bigg\rangle}}_{\!\!2}^{\!\!-1}}}
    {\bigg\rangle}}_{\!\!3}^{\!\!-1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, the innermost fraction could be dealt with using the standard `\left` and `\right`, I used the same construction for uniformity. Some negative space has been added to the superscripts and subscripts.

If you prefer a different vertical alignment, some more tricks are needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\bA}{\mathbf{A}}
\newcommand{\bI}{\mathbf{I}}

\newcommand{\leftrightangle}[1]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \hbox{%
      $\displaystyle\stretchleftright{\bigg\langle}{#1}{\bigg\rangle}$%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\[
  \bA_3+ 
  \leftrightangle{
    \frac{\bI}{\bA_2+
     \leftrightangle{
      \frac{\bI}{\bA_1+
       \leftrightangle{
         \frac{\bI}{\bA_0}
       }_{\!\!1}^{\!\!-1}}
     }_{\!\!2}^{\!\!-1}}
  }_{\!\!3}^{\!\!-1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since "A_1+" is aligned with the "elbow" of the angle bracket located to its right, might it be preferable to position "A_2+" next to its "elbow", rather than the fraction bar encased by the angle brackets? Similarly, should "A_3+" best be positioned next to the adjacent elbow as well?

Comment: @Mico The `+` are aligned to the fraction lines; by chance the innermost one is aligned to the elbow.

Comment: I suppose that if the OP wishes to do so, alignment on the elbows rather than on the inner fraction lines could be achieved via a couple of `\vcenter{\hbox{$...$}}` directives. :-)

Comment: @Mico Yes, but my impression is that this is the wrong approach anyway. I'll add the possibility.

Comment: Maybe the author and maintainer of the `scalerel` package can be talked into providing an option to provide automatic vertical alignment of the contents of the `\strethleftright` macro. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I guess one way to proceed is to load a math font package that provides extra-large angle brackets "out of the box".

One such package is [mtpro2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html). It provides the instruction `\LEFTRIGHT\langle\rangle{...}`, where `{...}` is the material to be typeset between the angle brackets. The height of the angle brackets made possible by this package does have a limit -- 10cm (4 inches). I trust (hope?!) that this limit won't impose a meaningful constraint on your typesetting needs.

Note that while the "full" `mtpro2` package isn't free of charge, its "lite" subset -- which is all you need for the example at hand -- is in fact free. Note further that `mtpro2` uses Times Roman-style fonts; this feature may, or may not, be to your liking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}         % for \cfrac macro
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}    % for `\LEFTRIGHT` macro
\newcommand{\bA}{\mathbf{A}} % two shortcut macros
\newcommand{\bI}{\mathbf{I}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \bA_3+ 
  \LEFTRIGHT\langle\rangle{\cfrac{\bI}{\bA_2+
     \LEFTRIGHT\langle\rangle{\cfrac{\bI}{\bA_1+
        \LEFTRIGHT\langle\rangle{\frac{\bI}{\bA_0}}_{1}^{-1}}}
     _{\!2}^{\!-1}}} % provide some spacing adjustments
  _{\!\!3}^{\!\!-1} % ditto
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the package that you proposed is not free.

Comment: @shhmn - The "lite" subset of the `mtpro2` package -- which is all you need for the expression shown above -- *is* free of charge. :-)

Comment: But I do not know If I try to send the latex source with this package to some journal (Elsevier for example) will be a problem or not?

Comment: @shhmn - I honestly don't know the answer to that question. I suppose Elsevier journals use a special in-house font which is quite different from Times Roman.